# Unable to change core-animated-pages with paper tabs

Tags: polymer

I'm trying to hook `core-animated-pages` with `paper-tabs` in my polymer appliaction. Everyghing looks cool , but I have trouble with changing `core-animated-pages` when I click on `paper-tabs` button 
I'm trying to use [This polymer tutorial](https://www.polymer-project.org/0.5/articles/spa.html) , my version is very similar to tutorial so it should work. Unfortunately I can see only first `core-page` active or my URL is changing for `http://myapp/#one or #two`

My code below:

```
 <template id="templ" is="auto-binding">
            <div layout horizontal flex>
                <paper-tabs id="tabs" valueattr="hash"  selected="all" class="progress-tabs" self-end>
                    <template repeat="{{page in pages}}">
                        <paper-tab>{{page.name}}</paper-tab>
                    </template>
                </paper-tabs>
            </div>

            <div layout horizontal center-center fit>
                <core-animated-pages valueattr="hash" selected="{{hash}}"
                                     transitions="slide-from-right">
                    <template repeat="{{page in pages}}">
                        <section hash="{{page.hash}}" layout vertical center-center>
                            <div>{{page.name}}</div>
                        </section>
                    </template>
                </core-animated-pages>
            </div>

        </template>
```

And script:

```
  <script>
    Polymer('progress-page', {
        ready: function () {
            var template = this.shadowRoot.getElementById("templ");
            template.pages = [
                {name: 'Single', hash: 'one'},
                {name: 'page', hash: 'two'}
            ];
        }}
    );
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the paper-tabs use 'selected' attribute to get the 'hash' value of selected tab:

```
<paper-tabs id="tabs" valueattr="hash"  selected="{{selected}}" class="progress-tabs" self-end>
```

Then us {{selected}} value to switch the core-pages:

```
<core-animated-pages valueattr="hash" selected="{{selected}}"
                                 transitions="slide-from-right">
```

So, 'selected' attribute passes the value between tabs and pages.